# Check if user has permission to execute file

Tags: bash, find

as in title: how to check if user(script parameter) have permission to execute file using `find` in bash?

I think is something with `-perm` but i tottaly dont now how to start with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use find as in the following example, given user as script parameter $1:

```
$ find /path/to/dir/ -user $1 -type f -perm -u+x
```

Comment: Thanks it works. But could u explain me what does it mean: -u+x ?

Comment: With -u+x you check permission bits for -u users (first three bits of permission mask)  with +x executable bit enabled.