# How to check if command exists for a user?

Tags: bash, shell

I install Pip for a user (not system wide) and I would like to check that pip is installed for that user in my script that I run with sudo: `sudo ./script.sh`

I know to check for a command with `command -v pip3` and that works when I enter it in the shell as the user.

But how can I check it in my script?

`command -v pip3` exit code is 1 because I am root (because of `sudo`).

`su -c "command -v pip3" "$SUDO_USER"` has exit code 1.

`sudo -u "$SUDO_USER" command -v pip3` says "command: command not found"

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42973925/1135424

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest is

```
sudo -u "$SUDO_USER" -i command -v pip3
```

The `-i` option causes `sudo` to pass the supplied command line to the user's configured shell using its `-c` option, instead of trying to execute the command directly. That's necessary because `command` is a shell built-in; it doesn't exist as a stand-alone executable. (The `-i` options runs a "login" shell. There is also the `-s` option which runs a non-login shell. See below.)

If you want to specify a shell explicitly you could do so instead:

```
sudo -u "$SUDO_USER" /bin/sh -lc "command -v pip3"
```

Again, a login shell is forced, here by using the `-l` option.

As a safety feature, `sudo` normally resets the `$PATH` to a "safe" value before executing the shell (or the single command). That value will not have any of the modifications made in the `/etc/profile` and `~/.profile` startup scripts, and without those modifications -- which add one or more user-specific directories to the path -- the shell will not find software such as `pip3` which has been installed for individual users.

Comment: This `-s` option seemed promising but does not work. Exit code returned is 1.

Comment: @Stephane: I hope I got it right this time. You have to use `-i`, not `-s`, so that a login shell is run. (Or `-lc` if you're invoking a specific shell.) I did a test which I think is as close as possible to what you're doing and it seems to work.

Comment: `-i` option worked! `echo $?` returned 0 this time. Thanks for your help rici.

Answer (score 0):

use following command by replacing $USER with the specific user name.

`sudo -H -u $USER bash -c 'command -v pip3'`

similarly, you can run any command as another user

syntax : `sudo -H -u $USER bash -c 'INSERT_COMMAND_HERE'`

Comment: Does not work. With `'command -v pip3'` exit code is 1 (should be 0). With just `'pip3'`, it says that pip3 is not found.